# Ionic-Cordova fails to find OneSignal plugin in the app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I am using cordova 6.0.0 and cordova-platform-android 6.0.0 for developing my ionic app.
I have added the one signal plugin in initialization scripts. The script looks like below.

```
sudo cordova platform add ios
sudo cordova platform add android
sudo ionic resources

sudo cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
sudo cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
sudo cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration
sudo cordova plugin add https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git
```

In my ionic app in the app.js file I called the OneSignal init method as below.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
    app.run(function () {

        var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
            //console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        };
        console.log('oneSignal plugin', window.cordova.plugins.OneSignal);
        window.cordova.plugins.OneSignal.init("my-one-signal-app-id",
            {googleProjectNumber: "my-google-app-id"},
            notificationOpenedCallback);

        window.cordova.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);


    });
});
```

But when I run the app it displays as below

```
oneSignal plugin undefined
app.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Is it an issue with cordova 6.0.0 or I have done any wrong with the approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 errors.
1. Instead of using window.cordova.plugins I have to use window.plugins
2. In my app a service overwrite the plugins. So it shows OneSignal undefined.
And It works fine for cordova 6.0.0 and cordova platform android 6.0.0.